# looping a data frame to create a boxplot

Tags: r, data-visualization, boxplot

i'm trying to get boxplot using R software in a data frame but there are lots of columns attached to the data frame. 
Here is the code

```
path = "E:/plot/2"
fileList = list.files(path=path,pattern="\\.teTestResult",full.names=T)
myfiles = lapply(fileList, read.csv,header=TRUE,sep=";" )

a <- data.frame(myfiles)
attach(a)
boxplot(Return~gama)
boxplot(Return~theta)
boxplot(Return~detectionsLimit)
boxplot(Return~NSMOOTH)
boxplot(Return~NREF)
boxplot(Return~NOBS)
boxplot(Return.1~gama.1)
boxplot(Return.1~theta.1)
boxplot(Return.1~detectionsLimit.1)
boxplot(Return.1~NSMOOTH.1)
boxplot(Return.1~NREF.1)
boxplot(Return.1~NOBS.1)
...
boxplot(Return.9~NOBS.9)
```

This code works, but it did not deliver a good one because it is very long. How can i simplify this using R?
Thank you so much for the help

~Update~

I'm trying to use the for loop because the variable name im trying to boxplot only differs in the number, so here it is

```
for (i in 1:9){
boxplot(Return.[i]~gama.[i])
    }
```

But, an error occured saying this

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'Return.' not found
```

I'm still witnessing much problems with R programming
Thank you so much for your replies.

Comment: please provide the variable names of your data.frame ; I would guess the way you accsessed the variables is wrong, you missed a$ and prbly should type `boxplot(with(a, get(paste0("Return.", [i]))) ~ with(a, get(paste0("gama.", [i])))`

Comment: @grrgrrbla Thanks for the reply, i've tried the attach(a) function to substitute a$.
and i have tried your code

`for(i in 1:9){
boxplot(with(a, get(paste0("Return.", [i]))) ~ with(a, get(paste0("gama.", [i])))
}`

but i experience error from the `[]`
it says like this,
`Error: unexpected '[' in:
"for(i in 1:9){
boxplot(with(a, get(paste0("Return.", [`

Comment: you (and prbly me too) forgot a `)` check all of them, please do a little thinking on your own

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you combine the list of dataframes with data.frame() function, you are cbind-ing the dataframes. if all the files are of the same structure I'd suggest you combine them using rbind:

```
library(dplyr)
for(i in 1:length(myfiles)) myfiles[[i]]$nr = i   # if you need to know the origin of the data
df = bind_rows(myfiles)
```

The distinction between the different files can be done by faceting, but since you need plots for different variables you probably can't shorten your code any further:

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(df, aes(factor(gama), Return)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~ nr)
ggplot(df, aes(factor(theta), Return)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~ nr)
ggplot(df, aes(factor(detectionsLimit), Return)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~ nr)
ggplot(df, aes(factor(NSMOOTH), Return)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~ nr)
ggplot(df, aes(factor(NREF), Return)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~ nr)
ggplot(df, aes(factor(NOBS), Return)) + geom_boxplot() + facet_wrap(~ nr)
```